# Java 1.4.2 IOException in getOutputStream() on AS400

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, ioexception, java1.4, iseries-navigator

I'm working under a AS400 system using Java 1.4.2, to get an XML but when I do the request using getOutputStream() I got an IOException and the message only returns the domain of the provider.

Here a part of my code:

```
try {
  url = new URL("https://test.example.it/27/xml/"); //Example URL...
} catch(MalformedURLException exMAL) {
  return exMAL.getMessage();
}

//Set parameters
LinkedHashMap params = new LinkedHashMap();
params.put("id", id);
params.put("password", password);
...
params.put("description", description);

String data = "";
Set set = params.entrySet();
Iterator i = set.iterator();

//Create URL of parameters
while(i.hasNext()){
if(data != ""){
  data += "&";
}
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
  data += me.getKey() + "=" + me.getValue();
}

try {
  //Create connection
  conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setUseCaches(false);

  //Do request
  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); //Error here
  wr.write(data);
  wr.flush();

  //Get resource
  InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
  outputData = readAll(is);
  } catch (IOException ioEx) {
    return "ERROR IOException: " + ioEx.getMessage();
  }
```

And the message error is "ERROR IOException: test.example.it".

I tested my code in a computer with Windows XP, Netbeans 4.1, Java 1.4.2 Build 19 (the same in the AS400) and I get the XML without problems.

I can compile my code into the AS400 but when I run the class in QSHELL or using a RPG Program i get the error.

Somebody knows what else I have to do or why I get this error?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Its a POST method, and actually I included setDoInput and setDoOutput in the code.

Now printing the exception I get this:

> **java.net.UnknownHostException: test.example.it**
>
> **ERROR IOException: test.example.it**

EDIT:

Looks like nslookup doesn't resolve the domain but after that I retry using the IP and now I have this error...

> **java.net.SocketException: The value specified for the argument is not correct.**
>   **ERROR IOException: The value specified for the argument is not correct.**

I think it would be a problem with AS400 security, probably should I add this domain in a list or edit a system value?

EDIT:

Using TCPCFG and then option 10, in this table of hosts I don't have the domain test.example.it, I suppose that I need to add this domain and IP, isn't it?

EDIT:

The version is V6R1M0. I added the IPs (Option 10. Work with TCP/IP host table entries) and now the AS400 resolve the domain but now I have a new problem.

> **java.net.ConnectException: A remote host refused an attempted connect operation.**

In the option 12 I have *SAME in all the options. For option 1 the following:

> ```
>  Internet         Subnet              Line      Line  Opt  Address          Mask             Description  Type 
>
>  127.0.0.1        255.0.0.0        *LOOPBACK    *NONE
>  151.208.xxx.xx   255.255.255.0    ETHLINE      *ELAN
> ```

I found in a group this: **"Is the 8080 port on the 400. Is the 400 setup to accept 8080 traffic via SSL"**.

How can I able the 400 to accept traffic?

Comment: Wait...are you trying to `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: Print the whole stack trace and post it in your question. NB `setDoOutput(true)` sets the method to POST.

Comment: UnknownHostException is generally a DNS lookup failure. Could you try nslookup on the command line to make sure that you can resolve the hostname?

Comment: It doesn't look like any connection to `AS400 security` at all. It looks more like a TCP/IP configuration problem. Copy/paste screen text into your question from the CFGTCP command options 1 and 12, please. Also paste from option 10 for the primary IP address.

Comment: You are *both* setting the request method to POST *and* calling `setDoOutput(true)`. You only need the latter, and you don't need `setDoInput(true)` at all.

Comment: Re CFGTCP option 10, there's no way to know what, if anything, should be there without seeing options 1 & 12. What is the OS version on your server?

Comment: Is the certificate trusted? You are using a https-url and this may cause problems, because of the certificate and also the used ssl-layer.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach Yes, actually I created a keystore using the certificate and I added it in my code using System.setProperty, but I think this is not the problem of "A remote host refused an attempted connect operation" because before I get the same error. And when I run my code in Windows-NetBeans it was not necessary.

Comment: IF *SAME is shown in CFGTCP option 12 parameters, it means that no host name nor domain name has yet been specified for the server. Given the question, host name should be set as 'test' and domain should be 'example.it'. (Replace with actual names.) If a DNS should be used, then any DNS addresses should also be set. See if that clears the problem. Various host servers might need to be restarted after the change. I don't know if TCP/IP itself needs to be restarted.

Comment: @user2338816 I had three IPs for the same domain and that causes the error. Using a unic IP solved the my problem. Thank you.

Comment: You should _always_ print out the whole stacktrace.  It contains more information than you think, which may help a senior programmer debug your problem.    If the problem is that the server isn't running (and you are not the one responsible for it) you need to ask the system administrator to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolve my problem, adding the IP and Domain in the host table (as I mentioned in a edit) but here is another problem.

The provider gave me one IP for requests and two more IPs for responses, an I added the three IPs with the same domain in the host table. I deleted two of three IPs and then I tried using only the IP for request and it worked!

Now the problem is that the request via Java is too slow! but that's another topic. Thank you very much for all.